# Wrong Favicons in Firefox

Tags: firefox, favicon

I am getting wrong favicons when I bookmark sites in Firefox 56.0 (64-bit).

For example, when I bookmark Stackoverflow.com, I get a favicon for Reddit.com.

Any idea why this would be, or how I can fix it?

Note: This is the *only site this is currently occurring with, but it happens every time when I remove/re-add the bookmark.*

**Stack Overflow Showing Reddit favicon:**

[image: Stackoverflow Showing Reddit Favicon]

**Correct favicon Shown in Media Tab:**

[image: Correct Favicon Shown in Media Tab]

**Edit 11/25/17**

Happening now on Drudge.

The accepted answer below does fix it.

[image: Drudge Wrong Favicon]

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Windows?

Comment: @random Reinstall Windows? Seems extreme to go there right out of the gate.

Comment: @random You must be joking.

Comment: I used to have an add-on to reset favicons, but it is no longer supported. You can check thru the current add-ons, but this one indicates it is no longer possible. [FavIcon Reloader up to FF 48 only](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/faviconreloader/) and [Developer reply by miacdo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/faviconreloader/reviews/905978/)

Comment: Does the correct favicon show in Page Info (Media tab)? Address something like "http://.../images/favicon.ico"? Also, is this problem restricted to your current profile?

Comment: @user3169 Yeah I used to use that also, it's not supported on this version of Firefox.

Comment: @user3169 Yes the correct favicon is showing on Page Info / Media tab.  I only have one profile.

Comment: Can you create another user profile, and if so does the problem happen in that profile too (to confirm that is where the problem is)? (Of course first back up your profile folder(s), just in case.) If it only happens in your profile, there are favicon db files in the profile folder, so I suspect that may be where the problem is coming from.

Comment: This used to occur frequently in older versions, and suddenly the issue has reappeared for me. If I remember correctly, clearing one of the tables in the SQLite databases could fix it for a while. But I don't think anyone discovered the underlying cause.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Close firefox, delete `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<your profile>\favicons.sqlite`

This is easier to do than peqhusus's solution, but it does mean you'll lose all cached favicons and have to reload your bookmarks to get the icons again.

Comment: This is an easier solution, as you mentioned, and fixes the issue, including between restarts.  Thanks.

Comment: For the records, that only exists starting from [Firefox 55](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Transferring_data_to_a_new_profile_-_Firefox). Before that (or well, at least since version 3) favicons were [inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Database) a [table](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/5k3rin/is_there_anyway_to_backuprestore_your_bookmarks/dbl2tb0/) in `places.sqlite`. Which one should be [very careful](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Bookmarks_history_and_toolbar_buttons_not_working_-_Firefox) to handle when downgrading/updating around FF 52-57.

Comment: Works well, there is a related video on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7u2jBitDcho&t=187s

Comment: The path on MacOS is `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<yourProfileFolder>/`

Comment: Deleting the favicons.sqlite was not enough for me. I also had to clear Firefox's cache too.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the best solution if you are only slightly annoyed...

What I usually do when this happens is go to

Bookmarks --> Show All Bookmarks --> Import and Backup --> Export Bookmarks to HTML file

Then open the bookmarks file, find the corresponding bookmark entry, then change
`ICON_URI="{URL}" ICON="data:image/png;base64,{data}`

to the URL of the icon and the base 64 encoded icon in png format

Then import the modified bookmarks file back into Firefox

Comment: Thanks, this DOES fix the issue, but is obviously not for your average end-user.  This was not presenting itself again until today, where I now had my Drudge Report bookmark toolbar completely disappear (although it was listed in the sidebar if I checked bookmarks).  So I removed and re-added, and get (oddly enough) the Reddit favicon for Drudge.

Answer (score -1):

Clearing the web cache should force Firefox to download the favicons again.

1. Close all the tabs except a new one
2. Go to `Tools > Options`
3. Click the `Advanced` on the left panel, then the `Network` tab
4. Find `Cached Web Content` and click the `Clear Now` to the right
5. Restart Firefox

Comment: Didn't do it.  For the record, Firefox 36 doesn't have an Advanced tab on the left panel anymore.  However, I did locate the clear Cached Web Content.  I restarted, yet still get a Reddit favicon for StackOverflow.  Perhaps I should file a bug with Mozilla?

Comment: It seems the "Clear Cached Web Content" only clears page data.  My favicons did not reload (from what I could tell) ... they were all there instantly when the browser loaded.

Comment: Your question states version 56, not 36. Which is it? Do other browsers load the favicons correctly?

Comment: That was a typo.  It's the latest Firefox 56 fully updated.