# Where comes this weird icon on Firefox's newtab-page from?

Tags: firefox

[image]

Randomly (?) some pages listed at the about:newtab in Firefox aren't showed with their favicon but instead this Stop having kids-symbol. If I inspect the source code when this happens, it looks like this:

```
<div class="top-site-icon rich-icon" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;);"></div>
```

Why does this happen? How do I fix it?

Comment: If it's favicon related, I recommend trying the [solution here](https://superuser.com/a/1287302/403203) and clearing cache.